# ARM Processor - thermal monitoring?

Tags: temperature, arm

Has anyone had success in getting temperature information from an ARM processor? I've tried using `lmsensor` but when I run `sensors-detect` the system locks up and has to be cold booted. Are there alternatives to this?

System: fanless PC running Debian 6.0.6

Comment: Which ARM-Processor is in your machine?

Comment: That's a great question. I can crack the case and (probably) read the chip info but I'm not sure what numbers are relevant.